# How to retrieve data from two tables with rows as columns? (dynamic pivot in MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have a two table (Table 1 and Table 2) in my MySQL db just like bellow image. 
I want to get data from two tables just like table 3, if my table 1 rows are increase then table 3 columns are increase. 
Is that possible to get data by one query by mysql?

```
CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `id` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `table_1` (`id`, `name`, `price`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'name1', '1.00', 1),
(2, 'name2', '2.00', 1),
(3, 'name3', '3.00', 1),
(4, 'name4', '5.00', 1),
(5, 'name5', '10.00', 1),
(6, 'name6', '15.00', 1),
(7, 'name7', '20.00', 1),
(8, 'name8', '50.00', 1);

CREATE TABLE `table_2` (
  `id` mediumint(6) NOT NULL,
  `table1_id` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `qry` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `total` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `table_2` (`id`, `table1_id`, `qry`, `total`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 1, 10, '10.00', '2017-12-02'),
(2, 2, 20, '40.00', '2017-12-02'),
(3, 3, 10, '30.00', '2017-12-02'),
(4, 5, 5, '50.00', '2017-12-02'),
(5, 4, 20, '100.00', '2017-12-03'),
(6, 6, 10, '150.00', '2017-12-03'),
(7, 7, 5, '100.00', '2017-12-03'),
(8, 8, 2, '100.00', '2017-12-03');
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of images, can you just provide the "sample data" as a formatted text tables? text is much preferred over images as we can re-use text.

Comment: Already mention the sql with sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is known as a "dynamic pivot query" because converting data into column headings isn't possible in standard SQL. You have to write a query that will generate a new query for you.

The **generated query code** will look like this:

```
SELECT t2.`date`
 , max(CASE WHEN name = 'name1' THEN t2.total END) AS name1
 , max(CASE WHEN name = 'name2' THEN t2.total END) AS name2
 , max(CASE WHEN name = 'name3' THEN t2.total END) AS name3
 , max(CASE WHEN name = 'name4' THEN t2.total END) AS name4
 , max(CASE WHEN name = 'name5' THEN t2.total END) AS name5
 , max(CASE WHEN name = 'name6' THEN t2.total END) AS name6
 , max(CASE WHEN name = 'name7' THEN t2.total END) AS name7
 , max(CASE WHEN name = 'name8' THEN t2.total END) AS name8
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t2.`date`
```

To **create that query** use the following (this is the **Dynamic SQL Query**)

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when t1.name = ''',
      Name,
      ''' then t2.total end) AS ',
      replace(Name, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from Table_1;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
'SELECT t2.`date`, '
, @sql
, ' from table_1 t1
inner join table_2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t2.`date`');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

see [this Demo](http://rextester.com/ZLLML18303)

```
+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|        date         | name1 | name2 | name3 | name4 | name5  | name6  | name7  | name8  |
+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 02.12.2017 00:00:00 | 10,00 | 40,00 | 30,00 | 50,00 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
| 03.12.2017 00:00:00 | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | 100,00 | 150,00 | 100,00 | 100,00 |
+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: "max(CASE WHEN name = 'name1' THEN t2.total END) AS name1" this part are need dynamic because in my table1 row are increase then column are increase

Comment: Sorry, what does that comment mean?

Comment: kindly see the comment again I have already edited. Basically I CASE part are need dynamic just like foreach loop to do this

Comment: YES, I display the first part ONLY so you can see what gets generated. **The SECOND part of my answer is the dynamic part.**